# How can i install ipa on iPhone device having version 10?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, web-application, appium

When i install ipa on real device having version 10 appium gives the error.

```
nfo: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

// My desired capability, appium version 1.4.3 and mac OS X elcaptain
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "IOS");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 5s");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.5.3");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID,"device id of my iPhone");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, ".ipa location");
```

Here is my appium log

```
2016-10-14 08:14:18:678 - info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)
2016-10-14 08:14:18:682 - info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
2016-10-14 08:14:18:686 - info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"/Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Desktop/Automation/app/LanguagesForIOS/Albanian/albanian.ipa","udid":"2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f","address":"127.0.0.1","sessionOverride":true,"noReset":true,"launchTimeout":"90000","log":"/Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Desktop/Automation/workspace/logs/appium1.log","nativeInstrumentsLib":true,"deviceName":"iPhone 5","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"10.0.2","showIOSLog":true,"defaultCommandTimeout":7200,"isolateSimDevice":true,"debugLogSpacing":true}
2016-10-14 08:14:18:687 - info: Console LogLevel: debug
2016-10-14 08:14:18:687 - info: File LogLevel: debug
2016-10-14 08:14:18:837 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
2016-10-14 08:14:18:840 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:18:848 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 11.477 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:20:566 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
2016-10-14 08:14:20:567 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:20:571 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 4.478 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:30:144 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
2016-10-14 08:14:30:144 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:30:146 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.796 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:149 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:149 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:151 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.263 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:153 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:154 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:155 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 2.016 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:174 - info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"10.0.2","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone 5"}}
2016-10-14 08:14:45:176 - info: Client User-Agent string: Appium (unknown version) CFNetwork/760.6.3 Darwin/15.6.0 (x86_64)
2016-10-14 08:14:45:176 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:176 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:176 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:176 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:177 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:177 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:177 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:178 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:178 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:178 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:178 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:178 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:178 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:178 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:179 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:179 - info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
2016-10-14 08:14:45:180 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:180 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:180 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:181 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:182 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:182 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:182 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:183 - info: *************************************
2016-10-14 08:14:45:187 - info: [debug] Using local .ipa from command line: /Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Desktop/Automation/app/LanguagesForIOS/Albanian/albanian.ipa
2016-10-14 08:14:45:187 - info: [debug] Copying local zip to tmp dir
2016-10-14 08:14:45:991 - info: [debug] /Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Desktop/Automation/app/LanguagesForIOS/Albanian/albanian.ipa copied to /var/folders/v2/s_nhjz013yvdf6djb20d1f640000gp/T/116914-4167-1ewtv5b/appium-app.zip
2016-10-14 08:14:46:008 - info: [debug] Unzipping /var/folders/v2/s_nhjz013yvdf6djb20d1f640000gp/T/116914-4167-1ewtv5b/appium-app.zip
2016-10-14 08:14:46:009 - info: [debug] Testing zip archive: /var/folders/v2/s_nhjz013yvdf6djb20d1f640000gp/T/116914-4167-1ewtv5b/appium-app.zip
2016-10-14 08:14:46:792 - info: [debug] Zip archive tested clean
2016-10-14 08:14:48:349 - info: [debug] Unzip successful
2016-10-14 08:14:48:351 - info: [debug] Using locally extracted app: /var/folders/v2/s_nhjz013yvdf6djb20d1f640000gp/T/116914-4167-1ewtv5b/Payload/LD_AsiaTopVol1Pro.app
2016-10-14 08:14:48:352 - info: [debug] Creating new appium session 63b2367a-579b-44a8-b15e-b02b79564713
2016-10-14 08:14:48:354 - info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
2016-10-14 08:14:48:356 - info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
2016-10-14 08:14:48:356 - info: [debug] Auto-detecting iOS udid...
2016-10-14 08:14:48:356 - info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
2016-10-14 08:14:48:358 - info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /var/folders/v2/s_nhjz013yvdf6djb20d1f640000gp/T/116914-4167-1ewtv5b/Payload/LD_AsiaTopVol1Pro.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
2016-10-14 08:14:48:359 - info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
2016-10-14 08:14:48:359 - info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /var/folders/v2/s_nhjz013yvdf6djb20d1f640000gp/T/116914-4167-1ewtv5b/Payload/LD_AsiaTopVol1Pro.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
2016-10-14 08:14:48:360 - warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't exist
2016-10-14 08:14:48:360 - info: [debug] Getting bundle ID from app
2016-10-14 08:14:48:367 - info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
2016-10-14 08:14:48:367 - info: [debug] Creating instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:48:370 - info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
2016-10-14 08:14:48:370 - info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
2016-10-14 08:14:48:371 - info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
2016-10-14 08:14:48:380 - info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
...
2016-10-14 08:14:48:380 - info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5923cadea0343e3f.js
2016-10-14 08:14:48:385 - info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5923cadea0343e3f.js
2016-10-14 08:14:48:388 - info: [debug] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog
2016-10-14 08:14:48:654 - info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f
2016-10-14 08:14:48:895 - info: [debug] App is not installed. Will try to install the app.
2016-10-14 08:14:48:896 - info: [debug] Installing ipa found at /Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Desktop/Automation/app/LanguagesForIOS/Albanian/albanian.ipa
2016-10-14 08:14:49:148 - info: [debug] Nothing found on device, going ahead and installing.
2016-10-14 08:14:49:462 - info: [debug] Starting command proxy.
2016-10-14 08:14:49:465 - info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
2016-10-14 08:14:49:466 - info: [debug] Starting instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:49:515 - info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:49:516 - info: Launching instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:49:518 - info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f
2016-10-14 08:14:49:519 - info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f com.eduVenture.LdAlbanian -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5923cadea0343e3f.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:49:520 - info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
2016-10-14 08:14:49:520 - info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
2016-10-14 08:14:50:578 - info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-10-14 13:44:50.577 instruments[4182:31576] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
2016-10-14 08:14:51:767 - info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
2016-10-14 08:14:51:768 - info: [debug] Killall instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:51:773 - info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
2016-10-14 08:14:51:773 - info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
2016-10-14 08:14:51:774 - info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
2016-10-14 08:14:56:777 - info: Launching instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:56:779 - info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f
2016-10-14 08:14:56:781 - info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f com.eduVenture.LdAlbanian -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5923cadea0343e3f.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:56:781 - info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
2016-10-14 08:14:56:781 - info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
2016-10-14 08:14:57:905 - info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-10-14 13:44:57.904 instruments[4188:31630] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
2016-10-14 08:14:58:847 - info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
2016-10-14 08:14:58:847 - info: [debug] Killall instruments
2016-10-14 08:14:58:852 - info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
2016-10-14 08:14:58:853 - info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #2
2016-10-14 08:14:58:854 - info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
2016-10-14 08:15:03:856 - info: Launching instruments
2016-10-14 08:15:03:858 - info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f
2016-10-14 08:15:03:859 - info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f com.eduVenture.LdAlbanian -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5923cadea0343e3f.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
2016-10-14 08:15:03:859 - info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
2016-10-14 08:15:03:860 - info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
2016-10-14 08:15:05:022 - info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-10-14 13:45:05.021 instruments[4194:31711] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
2016-10-14 08:15:05:967 - info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
2016-10-14 08:15:05:967 - info: [debug] Killall instruments
2016-10-14 08:15:05:972 - info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
2016-10-14 08:15:05:972 - info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3
2016-10-14 08:15:05:973 - info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
2016-10-14 08:15:10:975 - info: Launching instruments
2016-10-14 08:15:10:977 - info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f
2016-10-14 08:15:10:977 - info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 2d3e5f58ce14c287297ab008c3a731ad30bf715f com.eduVenture.LdAlbanian -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/hiteshbhardwaj/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5923cadea0343e3f.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
2016-10-14 08:15:10:978 - info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
2016-10-14 08:15:10:978 - info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
2016-10-14 08:15:12:164 - info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-10-14 13:45:12.163 instruments[4201:31757] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
2016-10-14 08:15:13:047 - info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
2016-10-14 08:15:13:048 - info: [debug] Killall instruments
2016-10-14 08:15:13:052 - info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
2016-10-14 08:15:13:052 - info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
2016-10-14 08:15:13:053 - info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
2016-10-14 08:15:13:054 - info: [debug] Reset not set, not ending sim or cleaning up app state
2016-10-14 08:15:13:055 - info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
2016-10-14 08:15:13:058 - error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup
2016-10-14 08:15:13:067 - info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2016-10-14 08:15:13:068 - info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
2016-10-14 08:15:13:072 - info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 27899.021 ms - 182 
2016-10-14 08:15:21:723 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
2016-10-14 08:15:21:725 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:15:21:728 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 6.104 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:15:31:440 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
2016-10-14 08:15:31:441 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:15:31:444 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 3.191 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:16:22:878 - info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
2016-10-14 08:16:22:879 - info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
2016-10-14 08:16:22:880 - info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.894 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Appium doesn't support iOS 10 yet (as of Oct 14,2016 [see here](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/appium-setup/platform-support.md))
As a temporary fix you can use ideviceinstaller directly to install the app

As far as I know there is no a single bug tracking appium's support for iOS 10 since it is a collection of smaller issues.

Comment: This could be a comment.

Comment: Seems a valid solution to the issue to me. @RSF could you improve it by adding a link to the offical bug and ideally linking the error messages returned.